# Optimizing a file_get_contents() script from a .json URL

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I need help for my code. I'm getting content from a .JSON file (URL) and I'm trying to optimize it because it's loading too slow. So i have the following code:

```
<?php 
$site = file_get_contents('website.com/content.json');
$obj = json_decode($site, true);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="result-' . $obj[$i]['id'] . '"></div>';
} 
?>
```

so everything looks fine, right? But here comes the hard part. In this simple loop I need to create another URL request so I can get information about the current result from another URL. Here we go:

```
<?php 
$site = file_get_contents('website.com/content.json');
$obj = json_decode($site, true);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="result-' . $obj[$i]['id'] . '">';
    $info = json_decode(file_get_contents("website.com/info/" . $obj[$i]['id'] . ".json), true);
    echo $info['content'];
    echo '</div>';
} 
?>
```

so that leads to much slower page load because of the many queries that needs to be ran. Any idea what to do? (I can't keep the additional info in single storage. It must be on different URL)

Comment: Is the site you are calling Yours? i.e. can you change the way the api works

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, the website I'm calling is not mine.

Comment: _Small Point_ If you are going to convert a perfectly good object into an array `$obj = json_decode($site, true);` WHY call the variable `$obj` and not `$array` :)

Comment: Then there is no way to optimise this

Comment: Тhere is a solution to every problem I guess.

Comment: If only that were so!

Comment: If the slowness is because of the number of requests which need to be made and the time it takes for those requests to receive a response then there isn't really a way to optimise it which is within your control (except perhaps to write this code in a language which properly supports making asynchronous http requests, so you could send several requests to the remote server in parallel)

Comment: Check the documentation for the site, see if there's a way for you to combine the two operations. There may be an option to the first call that tells it to include details, not just the ID.

Comment: But if not, there's probably not a way for you to do it. Complain to the API provider.

Comment: Well, as a partial way to solve the page load speed, if possible, just query the endpoints in async way while serving parts of the page via websocket.

Answer (score -1):

You can improve the performance with caching.
Caching can be done:

- on the **browser** with header:

```
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=600'); // cache in browser for 600 seconds
```

- on the **server**: in Memcache, Redis, files, database... You should use some [caching library](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=cache) that will simplify the job for you.

You can also cache the response from the API server that the `file_get_contents` returns for some amount of time.

You can also move building the page or fetching the API requests to some **asynchronous job**, e.g. crontab or message queue and store the content in database, Memcache or Redis.